# snipe-it копирует домен для изображений

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Установил `snape-it`, все вроде работает, но когда загружаю изображение, то адрес изображения становится
`https://domain.name/domain.name/uploads/manufacturers/manufacturer-image-TgWVueTze5.png`

Изображение загружается и будет доступно если убрать дубль в адресе `domain.name`. Может кто-то сталкивался с таким?

Answer (score 0):

В оф. документации не нашел ничего полезного и так не понял как это происходит, решил обойти эту проблему `nginx`-ом. А именно, просто вырезать часть `url` одной строчкой

```
rewrite ^/domain.name/(.*)$ /$1 break;
```

И все, все ссылки где будет идти дублирование домена будут обрезатся. Буду рад если это кому-то поможет.